# D3 update stacked bar chart based on non-constant amount of values in csv-file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

First off im new to javascript and D3 and have totally hit a wall. I've been trying to construct a stacked bar chart which is heavily based on the example by Mike Bostock (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208) but cannot update the chart once it has been rendered. I want the graph to update dynamically when a button is pressed. The part I'm struggling with is how to bind the new data to the bars. The csv-file im using has between 600-800 data rows that changes randomly depending on user input. So once the csv-file changes, i want to update the chart accordingly. I do not know if there are more or fewer data points in the new file(it could also be the same). This is what confuses me. I read up on the functions `enter()`, `exit()` and understand the concept but I cannot get it to work(guide found here https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/). Below is my attempt.

```
<style>

.axis .domain {
  display: none;
}

</style>

<h1>Hello world</h1>

<form name="sendForm" onsubmit="return update()" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="selectedRunId">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jslib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jslib/toast/js-toast-master/toast.js"></script>
<script src="../jslib/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(0.05)
    .align(0.1);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888"]);
d3.csv("vis_temp.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var keys = data.columns.slice(1);

  //data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.total - a.total; });
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.sample; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]).nice();
  z.domain(keys);

g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.sample); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth());

  g.append("g")
      .attr("id","xaxis")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")") //move x-axis to bottom
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5));
  var ticks = d3.selectAll(".tick text");

      ticks.attr("class", function(d,i){
        if(i%50 != 0) d3.select(this).remove();
      });
  g.append("g")
      .attr("id","yaxis")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", 2)
      .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .text("Time[ms]");

  var legend = g.append("g")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(keys.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width*0.95+5)
      .attr("width", 19)
      .attr("height", 19)
      .attr("fill", z);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width*0.95) //24
      .attr("y", 9.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
});
function update(){
        console.log("update called");
//++++ Generate new data
        var id = document.forms["sendForm"]["selectedRunId"].value;     
        var response = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "generateData.php",
                data: {selectedRunId: id},
                datatype: "html",
                async: false
        }).responseText;
        console.log("response="+response);
//---- Generate New Data
//++++ Update visuals accordingly

d3.csv("vis_temp.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var keys = data.columns.slice(1); 

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.sample; }));
  console.log("x-domain:"+x.domain);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]).nice();

  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.sample); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .exit().remove();
svg.selectAll("g#xaxis.axis")
     .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5));
  svg.selectAll("g#yaxis.axis")
     .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"));
  });

//---- Update visuals accordingly
        return false;
}

</script>
```

The issue is the "update" part. So the question is, how do I bind the new data correctly?

EDIT:

The data is in the following format:

`sample,prop_1,prop_2,prop_3
1,122,67,33
2,79,78,40
3,80,72,40`

EDIT2:

changed in `update()` line `.data(data)` to `.data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))`

Comment: In your `update()` function, the data you join to your main selection `svg.selectAll("rect")` doesn't depend on your ajax request so there is no change.

Comment: The ajax request is there simply to call `generateData.php` which alters the data file "vis_temp.csv". Is it not read again when i call `d3.csv` in my `update` function?

Comment: Sorry I didn't undestand this behaviour. Use the devtools of your browser to check if the second request is really made or if the browser use its cache.

Comment: Disabling cache did not help. I've verified that the data being requested in the `update()` function is actually different from the original data. Thus, new data is being loaded. I've also manually check the data file to verify that the data changes - which it did. I'm out of ideas to test :(

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in your d3 update pattern. I recommend you to read and understand [this series of articles](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) from Mike Bostock.

The concerning lines are the following:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.sample); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .exit().remove();
```

You perform operations only on entering and exiting selections. On the second drawing, d3 will reuse `rect` elements already in the DOM, but since you are not updating their properties, they will be unchanged.

Try this:

```
var selection = svg.selectAll("rect").data(data);

selection.enter() // ENTER
    .append("rect")
    .merge(selection) // ENTER + UPDATE
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.sample); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth());
selection.exit().remove(); // EXIT
```

Comment: My understanding is that `.data(data)` reapplies the data provided by `d3.csv` function. Since the raw data file has changed the existing rects should be changed as well. I tried your suggestion(and thanks for the assistance) but it seems there is a TypeError: `TypeError: d.data is undefined` which I cannot wrap my head around.

Comment: It's hard to debug this kind of error without knowing the structure of your data. It's weird to have this error with my suggestion and not your version.

Comment: I added the data structure to original post. I have also discovered that since I'm working with a stacked bar chart I think I need to use the `d3.stack` function before applying the data. So instead of calling `.data(data)` I call `.data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))`. I no longer get the error message but the line `.attr("x", function(d) { console.log("LOGGING:"+d); return x(d.data.sample); })` does not produce any output - which signals it is not being executed. Any suggestions?